# Dropdown options list to work like IE8

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

Dropdown options on IE8 gets cut down to width of select element but on IE11 it gets expanded to size of longest option value. I want to provide an unique user experience which will make it work like IE8; to cut options list width of select.

I tried css style for select option but it dint work. Any guidance?

Comment: what u have tried? my opinion is not to play with browser default components.

Comment: css:                                                                                                                   select option { width : 300px !important;}